# Tech Interview Question-Is my approach correct?

Tags: algorithm

Recently I was interviewed by a Software Company. I didnt make it through the first round itself.

Maybe I was too slow in forming ideas or solving problems and wasnt good enough for the company that i interviewed for.
I would like to have a second opinion about my interview and I cant find anyone better than the 
stackoverflow community.

So this interview was a basic one

1. Introduction
2. Why you have applied for this position?
3. One Techincal Question(Details Below)
4. Whats the Worst software you have used? Why? Improve
5. Whats the Best Software you have used? why Improve?

Original Technical Question(As asked by the interviewer)

Given a Range of numbers M.....M+N-1 I contruct an array of size N and replace one of the element in that array with a number. 
How will you find what element is replaced?

I asked him to repeat the question once more as I thought the input was not sufficient to solve the problem.
He repeated the statement ditto

Q. Then I asked him Is the array you got from the range of number in sorted order?
Interviewer: Its not necessary

Q Do we know the array before we replace an Element?
Interviewer: No

Then i started Writing some pseudo code(while doing loud thinking). I immediately realized that It wont work if the original array had duplicates. So I was stuk for a while thinking how the hell am gonna solve this.Then finally I asked questions that mattered

Q How do you choose the elements from the Range to form the array?
Interviewer: I have a range of number M, M+1, M+2....M+N-1. A number is picked only once. And I form an array of  size N.(Which essentially means no Duplicates and all elements in the range get picked)

Q What about the number you replace it with? Does it lie in the same range?
Interviewer: Yes it does.

Then everything became clear

**This was what he meant:**
Q I have a range of numbers starting from M , like M,M+1,M+2,M+3...M+N . I form an array of Size N, such that each element gets picked only once and the original array does not have any duplicates. I replace one of the elements in the array with a number in the same range. Find out what I picked from the range to replace?

This is equivalent to finding duplicates in array. Here after replacement there will be only one pair of duplicates We can easily find that out in O(N^2) time or O(nlogn) time. I gave him both the algorithms.

In the end I couldnt resist asking him "How did I perform in that question? He said Well you took a lot of time in answering.

*Clearly he was not satisfied with my approach to this question.

**What do you think I should have done differently while answering this question?***

Comment: You should probably mark this as community wiki, given that it's a rather subjective topic.

Comment: It is possible you answered correctly but it is also possible other candidates also answered correctly. Further, selection is not based on technical answers alone but personalities are important to a team manager - you really cannot know what the team manager was thinking or what he wanted.

In a lot of ways job interviews are like blind dates. You meet the person, then it doesn't matter if one of you is strongly attracted to the other, you cannot make the other person want to be your partner.

Comment: Yeah I understand that the selection process is not entirely based in answering the technical questions. What i was more interested in knowing was how could I have dealt with this question more efficiently?

like Should I have said upfront that this question is not solvable given the current Inputs.

Comment: With hindsight I think you could have asked up front whether your understanding of the question was correct. "a number" and "construct an array" are ambiguous: there is no one single way to "construct an array" given a range of values, and what does "a number" mean? pi? The square root of -1? Requirements-gathering is a reasonable thing to test at interview, although I don't know whether that's what the interviewer intended, or if he thought you'd understand that "construct" basically means "shuffle" and "a number" means "one of the *other* values from the array".

Comment: If the range was [M, M+N], you'll need a N+1 size array. You seem to make the range [M, M+N) part way, then revert to [M, M+N] in your conclusion.

Comment: "What do you think I should have done differently while answering this question?" - maybe to tell the interviewer that he should prepare his questions more carefully. After so many explanations, the problem still does not have a solution: replace M with M and try to find it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classical interview "riddle". It is in fact quite easy to solve in O(n) using the trick ralu described.

One of the things we teach in Data Structures 1, is that when your domain is limited, it might be possible to use that for a function better than O(nlogn) [obviously, sorting a domain without any additional knowledge cannot be done in less than that]. So when you know your domain - a little red light bulb should be turned on in your head somewhere :-)

I think that you should have immediately pointed out the question about the duplicates. It would make it clear that the question is not well formed. Otherwise, he just thought that you're slow (although it is in fact his fault...).

I also think that questions 4,5 are good questions. They show what experience an applicant has, and how the applicant thinks. So it may be possible that you failed the interview because of something you said there.

Comment: I'd potentially fail that. I'm simply incapable of keeping in my head a thousand lists of the top 5 best and worst ever blah blah. Ask me what my least favourite ever recipe is and what I'd do to improve it. I have no idea, but I'm not sure this tells you anything about how good I am at cooking. Then again, there's no rule against lying when asked a subjective question, or saying "I don't know about worst, but this is pretty bad" ;-)

Comment: I think that the "pretty bad" is probably good enough :)

To tell you frankly, I'm not sure how I'd answer that either, but the discussion after that is what matters!

Comment: @Anna This interview took place in my College campus, there were 30 mins time slots for each interview. When I reached the center the Interviewer was already running late and during my entire interview he kept on looking at the watch. So we couldn't discuss Q4 and 5 well , he was so keen to just rap it up.

Answer (score 6):

If I get question correctly you can solve this in O(n) time.

1. find two same elements using "hash" of size N
2. set one of this elements to 0.
3. make sum of elements and substract from calculated sum and you have the missing/replaced element (sum of elements is (2M+N-1)*(N)/2

**EDIT:**

Explanation of 1. point (find two same elements using "hash" of size N)

1. If you do not not know M find it (finding smallest element is O(n) , just one loop)
2. Alocate array h of size N  and set elements to 0 (can be type BOOL )
3. go trough table and check 1 at apropriate location off h
4. if it is 1 then you have colission, else set 1.

code for last part:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    if(h[a[i]-M] == 1) return i;
    h[a[i]-M] == 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate (1) please ?

Comment: 3 + 4 + 5 == 12 != (3 + 3) * 3 /2

Comment: @Rulu  
Can you elaborate more on point 3. If I am understanding it correctly, then taking the difference between the sum of elements and the expected sum according to the formula would only give the difference between the original element and the element with which it was replaced.  

For example, if the numbers are 3,4,5,6,7 (Sum is 25) and let us say I replace 6 with 4 so the new array is 3,4,5,4,7 (Sum is 23). The difference 2 is not the answer we are looking for.

Comment: But you know that 4 is the duplicate, so the difference, 2 + 4 (the duplicate) gives you the 6 that was replaced. The reasoning is similar if you replace 6 with 7.

Comment: All right, it's a "frequency" vector. I was thinking along the same lines, but with using bitmaps to save on space (n * 4 bytes versus n / 8 bytes). And in fact if you use this, you don't even need steps 2 and 3 since the only unset value is the one which was replaced

Comment: that is right it is even simpler. So step 1 only.
But point is that O(n) was our goal since O(n*log(n)) can be achived using sort

Comment: So we need to keep track of duplicates using some extra space

Answer (score 3):

Since no limits are specified on the amount of memory you are allowed to use, there is an O(N) solution: initialize an array A of size N to all zero.  Look at each element b in the list and mark A[b - M] = 1.  Then walk A and return c if A[c] == 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely impossible for anyone here to answer your question properly. You're writing this up *after the fact* in a clear manner.

- perhaps you rambled in your interview or did not express yourself quite as clearly as in this question!
- perhaps you didn't ask the right questions quickly enough
- perhaps you weren't quite as quick on the uptake after being given pointers (or not as quick as your competitors)
- perhaps the interviewer didn't like the fact that you started writing code before thinking through the problem

I have given umpteen interviews where I have felt that the person I am interviewing *knows the answer to the question I'm asking*. They just can't tell me: they're flustered or jumbled in their thinking. Some people's thought processes clearly run ahead of their mouths and they jump about confusingly. I'll wager a few of them go away and construct perfect answers like yours...

I can't tell you whether you did these things; perhaps your interviewer was being unreasonable. I know I've had interviews which didn't go so well for what I felt was no fault of my own. But at the moment, I find myself thinking things like:

- *could I put this person in front of a user?*
- *is (s)he joining the dots of this quickly enough?*
- *have they just waded right in without thinking it through?*
- *how do they compare to the person I saw an hour ago?*

Answer (score 0):

O(nlogn)  Solution Using B trees:..

Assuming we construct a binary tree as the array is made too ...since the complexity to construct an bin tree is O(n). 
Another assumption is that any element equalor lesser than is placed to the left of the binary tree.

Here we check each element in the array for its left node to be the same as the parent node for each subtree. To traverse the tree takes a time of O(logn).
We try to find a duplicate for each of the n elements. Hence overall time is O(nlogn).

O(n)  Solution using B trees and recursion:

We can construct a btree like mentioned above and using the same assumptions.
Check for each left child to be same as parent .
Do the same with both children . 
The stopping condition for the recursion is if child is NULL.
Hence each node is checked once . So the total time taken is O(n).

Comment: B-trees or binary trees?